# Can an antivirus really stop the broadAnywhere threat?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-2, security

I had a look at the diff where the [broadAnywhere threat is fixed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/37b58a4%5E!/#F0), and it's basically just `mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);` replaced with:

> Intent identityIntent = new Intent(); identityIntent.setComponent(new
>   ComponentName(SHOULD_NOT_RESOLVE, SHOULD_NOT_RESOLVE));
>   identityIntent.setAction(SHOULD_NOT_RESOLVE);
>   identityIntent.addCategory(SHOULD_NOT_RESOLVE); mPendingIntent =
>   PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, identityIntent, 0);

I installed an antivirus on my mobile, and it said it is now defending my mobile against the broadAnywhere threat.

But since applications are sandboxed in Android and the `identityIntent` is going to be passed from one application to another, how on earth is an antivirus going to be able to detect what `identityIntent` is being passed between applications? Will an antivirus really be able to defend/protect a mobile phone from the broadAnywhere threat?

Comment: Its almost 1.5 years since this question was posted... Can't anybody answer this question?

Comment: It has been answered here, I believe: http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2015/01/is-androids-broadanywhere-really-threat.html